# Removing numerous ‘homepage’ entries from Contacts.app with AppleScript extremely slow

Tags: icloud, applescript, ms-office, contacts

A syncing issue with Outlook left me with hundreds, if not thousands of duplicate contacts. After managing to merge duplicates without Contacts crashing, I was left with 177 contacts, most of which with many repeat homepage entries. Rather than dying of boredom removing these by hand, I put together some AppleScript to do this for me, thinking that this would take a few minutes. It’s been a week now – the script starts well enough but soon slows down continually and also takes more and more memory from the system, until the spinning beachball of doom appears halting the script. One issue is that I seem to only be able to delete a contact’s urls one at a time in sequence, instead of all at once.

So the question is, what have I got wrong making this script near useless? Could it have something to do with iCloud syncing? Or is AppleScript inherently inefficient? (The constant saving is there because of the random times the script would cease functioning.):

```
tell application "Contacts"
    activate
    with timeout of 72000 seconds
        set myPeople to people
        set numPeople to (count of myPeople)
        repeat with i from 1 to numPeople
            set myGuy to item i of myPeople
            set myGuyName to get name of myGuy
            set personUrls to (the urls of myGuy whose value contains "outlook")
            set urlNum to count of personUrls
            if urlNum > 0 then
                repeat with j from urlNum to 1 by -1
                    log ((time string of (current date)) & " – [" & i & "/" & numPeople & "] " & myGuyName & " (" & j & "/" & urlNum & "): " & (the label of item j of personUrls))
                    delete item j of personUrls
                    save
                end repeat
            else
                log "No problematic URLs found for " & myGuyName
            end if
            if note of myGuy is not missing value then set note of myGuy to ""
        end repeat
        save
        log "Final save"
    end timeout
    return
end tell
```

Comment: First I have to say that I don't use iCloud and aside from Time Machine I only sync data on my iPhone with my MacBook Pro. That said I recently had an issue where I had to take my contacts from a temporary Android phone and merge them with Contacts on macOS and with a new iPhone. I exported everything to vCards (.vcf) and then with bash shell scripting using utilities like `awk`, `sed`, etc. it took seconds to clean up the mess and then I deleted contacts on my phone and in Contacts and imported the cleaned up .vcf file and synced the phone. Now both have the exact same info and how I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CJK’s answer didn’t work for me, but the response given in the *Events* tab of Script Editor gave me the basis of an alternative that appears to work as intended:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    delete (every url of every person whose value contains "outlook")
    set note of every person to missing value
    save
end tell
```

---

<sub>**Added by [*@CJK*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/266364/cjk) on 2019-04-03:**</sub>

<sup>Rather than forcing AppleScript to enumerate `every person` in your address book twice, which is, in general terms, a costly operation, store a reference to the collection in a variable, which you can then use repeatedly with a lot less overhead:</sup>

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set _everyone to a reference to every person
    set _homepages to a reference to _everyone's urls

    delete the _homepages where the value contains "outlook"
    set _everyone's note to missing value

    save
end tell
```

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* 2.7  *System version:* 10.13.6</sup>

This is what is returned by the *Events* or *Replies* tab when running the original refactored code:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    delete every url of every person whose value contains "outlook"
    set note of every person to missing value
end tell
tell application "Script Editor"
    save current application
end tell
```

I’m guessing that nothing appears to happen because (I think) changes made to the contacts only work once saved. @CJK’s new version above works as intended, however.

Now, is it as easy to whittle down a bunch of duplicate items to one as it clearly is to delete all of them?

Comment: That is very, very strange, given that, in fact, your code block here is _identical_ to mine at the end, and it's only the syntax that is slightly different, which is impossible to be the cause, or the rest of AppleScript would be broken too.  I wonder if it's a scripting bug in _Contacts_.  Can I ask what version of macOS you're using ?  Also, what was the response given that you mentioned ?

Comment: I hope you don't mind the remark I added to the bottom of your answer here.  It seeemed pertitent given the question and answer were focussing on efficiency.  Hope that works on your system; it does on mine.  Feel free to roll back the edits to restore the previous version of your answer if you don't want my addendum to remain.

Answer (score 1):

That's bold to assert AppleScript being inefficient (vague term) as a cause.  Of course, it very well could be a factor, but it feels a little awkward to say that your script is inefficient, and woefully so.  I don't know if that is the *only* reason the script runs slowly, but it's a good place to start making fixes, which I'll outline by extracting problem lines in your code:

```
⚠️ set myPeople to people
```

Redundant.  There is little point in assigning a value to a variable that you don't intend to use in a meaningful way (e.g. for manipulating data without changing the source, or, if you really need to, for making scripts easier to read or debug).  Nowhere else in your script do you make a reference to `myPeople`, except for one other line that is also redundant.  Therefore, don't waste an operation (and potentially memory, but not really in this particular case) creating a variable you don't need.

```
⭕️ set numPeople to (count of myPeople)
```

Redundant in principle (I note that you do log the value of `numPeople`, though it's only used to give you an index reference, which you don't need to know; see next comment).

```
⚠️ repeat with i from 1 to numPeople
       set myGuy to item i of myPeople
```

Ignoring for a moment the log call that references `numPeople`, then the entire purpose of the declaring `numPeople` is to allow iteration through a list by way of a counter variable (`i` in your case) that is used to access each item through its index (position),  i.e. `item i of myPeople`.  There are many instances where this would be very appropriate, but it is slower than letting AppleScript worry about how it accesses list items, which it can take off your hands using this syntax: **`repeat with myGuy in people`**

```
⚠️ set urlNum to count of personUrls
```

Redundant, for the same reason as above.  As an additional note, I would personally choose to evaluate the size of a list using the `length` property.  This doesn't apply to nested lists of lists for which you want to include deeply-nested items in the final number, but that's not the case here.

As soon as a script has evaluated (retrieved) an object, its properties will have been retrieved as part of that evaluation.  `length` is a property of a list object, and its a simple, unary value (an `integer`), so accessing that value will always be quick.  `count` is a command.  It performs some undisclosed operation(s) and returns a value.  I don't know what those operations are, and they will be performed at the C-language level, so probably (almost certainly) aren't slowing this script down at all.  But, in principle, it's something to bear in mind as there are other situations<sup>†</sup> a command and a property seemingly do the same thing, but the property is demonstrably faster.

<sup><sup>†</sup>Can't recall them right now.</sup>

```
⭕️ if urlNum > 0 then
```

Redundant, in principle.  There is an `else` clause that you might insist on keeping, but the only thing it does it to log the fact that nothing was done.  If someone asked me how to intentionally slow a script down because it's just too efficient, this might be one of my answers.

```
⚠️ repeat with j from urlNum to 1 by -1
```

This is flagged for both the use of a counter variable, `j`, and for its position within the `if` block.  If `urlNum` were set to 0, the repeat loop hear would never be entered, and the script would continue executing the code that follows it.  But, as will become clear, the entire `repeat` block is redunant.

```
⚠️ log ... (the label of item j of personUrls))
   delete item j of personUrls
```

I'm questioning the necessity of this `log` command as a whole.  It's certainly not as self-defeating as the one I mentioned earlier, but it does perform a `current date` command call, and a lookup in the `personUrls` list object.

- *In situations where you do require a counter variable to iterate through a list, do as you did above, and declare a variable to which can assign the current list item's value, i.e. `set hisURL to item j of personalUrls`.  In crude terms, each time you ask AppleScript for [the value of] `item j of...`, it must access the list object and perform a look up, which is a relatively expensive operation to perform.  Declaring a variable means the lookup is only performed once, then the value (a copy of the original) is stored in memory, for which retrieval is quick and easy in computational terms.*

Returning to the value being logged, its worth seems negated by the immediate deletion of the URL data.  I'm wondering if you might have just wanted a means of tracking where your script had reached in its run, which needn't be so involved.  Using your counter variables, you could simply: **`log [j, i]`** (logging their upper bounds once is sufficient, since those values don't change during a loop).

The `delete` command, when viewed in the context of the repeat loop in which it is called, is going to be slowing things down a lot.  You are iterating through *every* item in a collection in order to delete it...

```
⚠️ save
```

...*then* you save your changes.  How would I intentionally make my script run as slowly as possible ?  I would perform a save operation on the entire address book a number of times equal to `numPeople * urlNum`.  This value is at least 177, but it's actually multiples of this.  The total number of times you need to perform the `save` operation, I imagine, would be 1.

### The Knock-On Effects:

Now we know that iterating over `PersonUrls` was not necessary, the entire `repeat` block can be replaced with the line: **`delete every url of myGuy whose...`**.

- *As something to be mindful of, any script that features nested `repeat` loops are going to be inefficient: the number of operations performed is a product of each list's size.*

<sup>I actually note that you do mention attempting to delete a contact's URLs en masse, which didn't work for you, forcing you to do it iteratively.  However, as you didn't supply any code showing the methods you tried to do mass-deletion, it's not possible to offer insight into why it failed for you.</sup>

Removing the `repeat` block has a cumulative benefit of negating the parent `if` block, irrespective of my earlier comments on it.

- *Conditionals can be expensive expressions to evaluate, particularly performing 177 of them that were never needed.*

### The Refactored Code:

Continuing back up through the script, the preceding variable declarations all become redundant, which leads to the eventual conclusion that your entire script is functionally equivalent to:

```
use application "Contacts"

tell (a reference to every person)
    delete (its urls where the value contains "outlook")
    set its note to missing value
end tell

save
```

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* 2.7  *System version:* 10.13.6</sup>

### What Now ?

Was your ultimate goal to remove *all* URLs containing "outlook", or did you plan on retaining one "outlook" URL for contacts that have them ?

Comment: That’s great information! A couple of explainers: originally the code (can you tell I’m not well versed in AppleScript?) had far less `save` points because the script would eventually hang and/or I would get low memory warnings. The iterators and log statements are all to monitor what has been processed - and to see how much time has expired between deletions. So there’s no reason for any of that to be there in a properly functioning script; it’s just there for my benefit!

Comment: Also, the script is to delete every url containing ‘outlook’, but there is definitely scope for deleting all-but-one of a particular item.

Comment: @user3439894 I wanted to remove _all_ urls that contained ‘outlook’ (specifically web-addresses beginning `ms-outlook` as these were useless, but some contacts do have duplicate urls for company websites where it would be useful do retain only one.

Comment: Nice to see you back answering questions! Excellent information given in your answer! +1